# Get parameters from a response - Java

Tags: java, parameters, response

Hello and thanks for taking the time to answer my question.

I am a .NET guy who recently switched to Java for the new job. I need to implement a payment gateway and I'm using the API provided by the bank. There it's stated that I need to send a post request to a url with given parameters and in the response I'll get a number of parameters based on which I need to take further actions. I know how to do this with C# and .NET but was wondering what is the way to go with Java?? Does not seem very intuitive to me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look at the [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/) library, particularly the [examples](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/examples.html) page.

Comment: You could take a look in http://pdf.coreservlets.com/Servlet-Basics.pdf. If you are familiar with the MVC pattern, you could also take a look at Struts or JSF.

Comment: Isn't this a question about setting up an Http client, not a server?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you're getting an object back after you send a request. You can check the value of the fields in that object and do an if on it.

So if you get an object obj after the request is sent.

```
if(obj.getX() == y){
    doSomething();
}else{
    doSomethingElse();
}
```